# MongoDB aggregate + $match + $group + Condition filter

Tags: mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query, jenssegers-mongodb

**Here is my code :**

```
$profiles = Profile::raw()->aggregate([
            [
                '$unwind' => '$channels'
            ],
            [
                '$match' => [
                    'channels.sign_up' => true,
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$match' => [
                    "city_id" => request()->input('city_id'),
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$match' => [
                    'created_at' => [
                        '$gte' => request('start_date', date('Y-m-d') . ' 00:00:00'),
                        '$lte' => request('end_date', date('Y-m-d') . ' 23:59:59'),
                    ]
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$group' => [
                    '_id' => '$channels.slug',
                    'user_count' => ['$sum' => 1]
                ]
            ],
            [
                '$sort' => [
                    "user_count" => -1
                ]
            ]
        ]);
```

where 2nd and 3rd `'$match'` is optional based on filter. if `city_id` is not empty than i have to add 2nd `'$match'` and if `start_date` and `end_date` is not empty than i have to add 3rd `'$match'`.

I am using [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).

Need suggestion :)

Comment: Can you add the sample data (a few sample documents) and the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$and` condition.

> Please check below code that help you.

```
var matchConditionsArray = [];
matchConditionsArray.push({ 'channels.sign_up': true });

if (request.city_id) {
  matchConditionsArray.push({ 'city_id': request.city_id });
}

if (request.start_date && request.end_date) {
  matchConditionsArray.push({ "created_at": { $gte: request.start_date } }, { "created_at": { $lte: request.end_date } });
}

aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: matchConditionsArray
    }
  },
  ....
]
```